# Вывод текста НЕ в консоли, а в программе

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, input, pyqt5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый день!

Только начал изучать Python.
Пишу 1-ю программу.

Через QT Designer набросал тело программы.
Не могу сообразить, что необходимо, для того, чтобы текст появлялся в окне (QTextBrowser), а не в консоли.

Подскажите, пожалуйста....

```
****Корпус программы:
___________________________________________________________
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(230, 333)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 151, 61))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.text_input = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 191, 31))
        self.text_input.setObjectName("text_input")
        self.text_print = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 71))
        self.text_print.setObjectName("text_print")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Суперпрограмма"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей?"))



****Программа:
_____________________________________________________

    import sys
    # Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
    from design import *
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

            # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
            self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

        # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
        # при нажатии на кнопку                  
        def MyFunction(self):
             print ("Этот текст должен быть в окне приложение, а не консоли")



    if __name__=="__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = MyWin()
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Так вам вряд ли кто-то будет отвечать. Приведите код в вопросе текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: ну вы как бы принтуете это априоре как бы вывод в консоль

Comment: Нужно не через print, а через соответствующий метод виджета (setText() или что-то похожее).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) отнаследован от [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) поэтому у него есть все методы от [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html).

Вам подойдут следующие:

- [QTextEdit::setText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText) - принимает текст и пытается определить его формат (метод объекдиняет setHtml и setPlainText). Например поймет что вы передали строку HTML (`"Hello <b>Qt</b>!"`)
- [QTextEdit::setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) - принимает строку в HTML, включает в себя рендеринг HTML
- [QTextEdit::setPlainText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText) - принимает простой текст

Пример:

```
def MyFunction(self):
    text = "Этот текст должен быть в окне приложение, а не консоли"

    print(text)
    self.ui.text_print.setText(text)
```

---

**PS.**

Для получения текста используются:

- [QTextEdit::toPlainText()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText)
- [QTextEdit::toHtml()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop)

---

**UPD.**

Еще, запись из `print` в виджеты можно автоматизировать.

Можно сделать класс-обертку с методами `write` и `flush`, используемыми в `sys.stdout` (туда `print`, по-умолчанию, пишет) и `sys.stderr`, добавить функцию-обработчик (или сигнал, если `Qt`)

Теперь, всё, что будет написано в `print` попадет в виджеты

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ce4a5cdee90c10d49644d091026b8cf5b8f7bcd1/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__redirect_print_stream_to_qtextedit.py#L13):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QMenuBar, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal


class OutputLogger(QObject):
    emit_write = Signal(str, int)

    class Severity:
        DEBUG = 0
        ERROR = 1

    def __init__(self, io_stream, severity):
        super().__init__()

        self.io_stream = io_stream
        self.severity = severity

    def write(self, text):
        self.io_stream.write(text)
        self.emit_write.emit(text, self.severity)

    def flush(self):
        self.io_stream.flush()


OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT = OutputLogger(sys.stdout, OutputLogger.Severity.DEBUG)
OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR = OutputLogger(sys.stderr, OutputLogger.Severity.ERROR)

sys.stdout = OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT
sys.stderr = OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()

        OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT.emit_write.connect(self.append_log)
        OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR.emit_write.connect(self.append_log)

        menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        menu = menu_bar.addMenu('Say')
        menu.addAction('hello', lambda: print('Hello!'))
        menu.addAction('fail', lambda: print('Fail!', file=sys.stderr))
        self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

    def append_log(self, text: str, severity: OutputLogger.Severity):
        text = repr(text)

        if severity == OutputLogger.Severity.ERROR:
            text = f'<b>{text}</b>'

        self.text_edit.append(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    print('Go!')

    app.exec()
```